# What masteries synergize with Warfare in Titan Quest?

Tags: titan-quest

I just hit level 8 in Titan Quest and found that I can choose a secondary mastery. Warfare is my primary. I looked through the various options for a while and was a bit overwhelmed.

What secondary masteries (and skills) work in tandem with the Warfare abilities, and which don't work? For example, I saw one ability that looked like it would conflict with my "assign this to left click" ability, so I figure I should stay away from that sort of thing (unless... do they stack?).  Are there any particularly effective/fun combos to look at?

Answer (score 6):

If you have the expansion pack, Dream mastery really goes well with almost anything (it's kinda overpowered, actually).

I played a Warfare / Defense (Conqueror) character once, it was quite a blast. It's more or less the straight up tank / warrior build, although you can specialize towards offense or defense by investing in either dual wield or shields.

[TitanCalc](http://www.titancalc.com/) is invaluable for trying out sample builds / seeing what you think you'd like to play.

Answer (score 1):

I choose assassins (warrior & rogue), but I more like to use calculate strike (rogue) in my left click because it will do more damage then onslaught. with dual wielding, attack speed (warrior)and damage from assassin it will be god of war..

Answer (score 0):

Rogue was always my favorite mastery to pair with warfare. Blade Honing and the poison skills synergize really well if you are doing dual wield

Answer (score 0):

My main character is a complete tank, taking warfare as his primary mastery and defense as his secondary. Adrenaline boosts his healing rate more frequently than you might think (5% chance, but it sure goes off a lot). Quick Recovery helps him wade into large groups of foes and not lose his shield protection. Focus ups his chance of shield block, which means less damage and more survivability. There are just so many ways the defense mastery is a great second; they're practically made for each other.

The only negative comment I can make is that I focused too much on melee combat. The end boss from the original game gave my main character fits because he does so much damage in melee range. I basically had to run around plinking with a bow and dodging attacks, running in close for a big hit every now and then, while sucking down potions. It made that boss battle a lot more stressful. Other than that, though, my tank waded through the game slaughtering pretty much everything else with gleeful abandon. You should take a look at the following site, which gives you stats on all the masteries:

http://www.gamebanshee.com/titanquest/skillmasteries.php